# NamedFieldPuns, Pattern matching using variable name

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

data Factory = Factory { fId :: Int}
data Link = Link Int Int Double

hasLinkTo :: Factory -> Link -> Bool
hasLinkTo Factory{fId} (Link fId _  _) = True
```

Got error

```
• Conflicting definitions for ‘fId’ Bound at: <source.hs> In an equation for ‘hasLinkTo’
```

I know using variables could fix it,

```
hasLinkTo Factory{fId=a} (Link b _  _) = a == b
```

**I want to ask for**

- reason of compilation fail, to better understand how pattern matching work.
- is there any idiomatic way to write the function?

for example: if I want to extract what link to a node `i`, I want to write something like this

```
connected :: Int -> Link -> (Int, Double)
connected i (Link i j d) = (j,d)
connected i (Link j i d) = (j,d)
```

Is there any way to check for (==) using only pattern matching on non-numeric literals?

`connected 0 (Link 0 j d) = (j,d)` is working fine. but the above example won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell only allows linear patterns, where each variable can appear at most once. I believe that this was a deliberate design choice. Theoretically speaking

```
case e1 of C x x y -> e2 ; ...
```

could be automatically translated to

```
case e1 of C x1 x2 y | x1==x2 -> e2 ; ...
```

This would mean that non linear patterns require an additional `Eq` constraint for the types of non-linear variables. Further, it could be argued that it is possible for a programmer to accidentally reuse a variable by mistake, which would be silently ignored and lead to the unintended semantics if we allowed non-linear patterns.

Probably, the Haskell designers felt that adding `| x1==x2` to a pattern was not too cumbersome and makes the intent more explicit.

For numeric literals, however, they kept this translation. A pattern

```
case e1 of K 0 y z -> e2 ; ...
```

does translate to

```
case e1 of K x y z | x==0 -> e2 ; ...
```

and does require `Eq`. Since `0` is not a variable, we no longer have the issues of non-linear patterns.

Anyway, the idiomatic way is to add guards like `| x1==x2` to non-liner patterns.
You can't use only pattern matching for this at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Record punning with `Factory{fId}` is only syntactic sugar which GHC expands to `Factory{fId=fId}`. This declared a variable named `fId`  with the value of the field named `fId` from the `Factory` record.

Furthermore, pattern matching only declares variables. It does not allow you to compare them by repeating the same name. Consider an attempt to compare equality:

```
eq a a = True
eq _ _ = False
```

This is a simple example that tried to do the same thing you are. It will not compile, though.

In the same way, the compiler complains because you declare two variables when you do `(Link fId _ _)`. This is not allowed. Instead you need to use another name and explicitly compare the two:

```
hasLinkTo Factory{fId} (Link fInd' _ _) = fId == fId'
```